# C#/.NET Macro Recording and Playback

Tags: c#, .net, macros

I'm in charge of taking an Excel VBA app and turning it into a stand alone piece of software. The main point of the functionality is to be able to record macros and play them back, think Website testing, mass SAP entries, anything a macro would be good for. I am not looking to re-invent the wheel, but I won't have the ability to install 3rd party macro recorders either. Which libraries or toolkits would you recommend I look at before getting started? Someone has recommended AutoHotkey to me, but as far as I can tell, it is standalone and doesn't exactly work inside of an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a sample Global Mouse and Keyboard library [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalmousekeyboardlib.aspx), that in my initial testing seems to be compatible with at least .NET 3.5 (and probably others). The demo applications show the proper use of tracking events and also contains a demo macro recorder. So far, this is the option that I'm pursuing, but if anyone else knows of better toolkits/libraries let me know!

Answer (score -1):

You might be interested in looking at QAliber Test Builder:

http://www.qaliber.net/testbuilder.php

It's open source, by the way.

Comment: That's for test building, he is looking for macro stuff. It needs to do more than just testing.

Comment: True, it doesn't exactly record macros like Excel does, however, you can record keystrokes and mouse clicks in QAliber, albeit probably not as conveniently as Excel does.

Comment: @DeanMeehan: i posted this 4 years ago.